# Is it possible to make dispatch_queue_t empty?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I cannot find any information about it. I have a `dispatch_queue_t` in my application where I put some tasks to do. But these tasks take some time and it happens that sometimes they shouldn't be called any more so I would like to clean out queue. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use NSOperationQueue for these capabilities - much more convenient. After adding operations to a queue, you can cancel them and even cancel all pending operations if needed.

Here's a good tutorial to get you started:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues

Comment: Looks like something what i need but the problem is that i want to clear out the queue which is used in Evernote SDK Api and i think it will be a lot of work to do if i would decide to change it there.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't remove items from a dispatch_queue_t. The two options you have are:

1. Have you work items check if they've been cancelled before doing their work
2. Suspend the queue; this won't remove the items, but it will stop them from running

Comment: I worked a bit with Evernote SDK and changed it for NSOperationQueue and as you wrote, first i'm checking if task have been cancelled.